# consuming wcf services in android and android-wcf session management

Tags: wcf-security, android-ksoap2

How do i generate the following soap envelope in android in order to consume wcf services...
the following envelope is generated in c# and caught by fiddler2..

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7be47300-e1a9-4f16-8d79-8e1bd52974cb</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="0d0b0e9e-4783-44a6-85ed-2f36eb4ec1c3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">6e45258f-1a8f-47f1-bed8-78172465df1c</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://test.parkingware.com:6060/Parkingware.Reservation.Service/ReservationService.svc</a:To>
</s:Header>

<s:Body>
    <trust:RequestSecurityToken Context="uuid-7843886f-5c12-4843-8ac2-1ccf8636e0a7-1" xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
        <trust:TokenType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512/sct</trust:TokenType>
        <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
        <trust:KeySize>256</trust:KeySize>
        <trust:BinaryExchange ValueType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/tlsnego" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">FgMBAFoBAABWAwFSpZ2WydPrK+SLYmvHk/bH914LbdddJStkVnE3ZLR2swAAGAAvADUABQAKwBPAFMAJwAoAMgA4ABMABAEAABX/AQABAAAKAAYABAAXABgACwACAQA=</trust:BinaryExchange>
    </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
</s:Body>
```